# Sorting upon the first element of a nested list and show that as numerical values

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, sorting

I wish to sort the below list upon the first elements:

```
 {{1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[2]), {{1, 11}, {1, 12}, {2, 11}}}, 
 {-1 - Sqrt[2], {{5, 11}, {5, 12}}}, 
 {1/2 (1 - Sqrt[2]), {{1, 9}, {1, 10}}},
 {1 - Sqrt[2], {{7, 9}, {7, 10}}}, 
 {1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]), {{1, 7}, {1, 8}}}}
```

The desired output can be shaped as:

```
{{-2.414, {{5, 11}, {5, 12}}}, 
 {-1.207, {{1, 11}, {1, 12},{2,11}}}, 
 {-0.414, {{7, 9}, {7, 10}}}, 
 {-0.207, {{1, 9}, {1,10}}}, 
 {0.207, {{1, 7}, {1, 8}}}}
```

where the first elements are numeric values (without `Sqrt` symbols) and just for `3-digit` precision. 
I have tried with `N` function. But the problem gives rise the effects on any pairs for example output be shaped as `{-2.41421, {{5., 11.}, {5., 12.}}}` (with a dot after `5` or `11`. 
Another problem is related to sorting of list just based on the first elements and NOT other elements.

Comment: If you want to keep the exact forms of the first element you can use `SortBy[lst, First[N[#]]&]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SortBy[MapAt[N, lst, {All, 1}], First]
```

> {{-2.41421, {{5, 11}, {5, 12}}}, {-1.20711, {{1, 11}, {1, 12}, {2, 
>       11}}}, {-0.414214, {{7, 9}, {7, 10}}}, {-0.207107, {{1, 9}, {1, 
>       10}}}, {0.207107, {{1, 7}, {1, 8}}}}

```
SortBy[N @* First] @ lst
```

> {{-1 - Sqrt[2], {{5, 11}, {5, 12}}}, {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[2]), {{1, 
>       11}, {1, 12}, {2, 11}}}, {1 - 
>      Sqrt[2], {{7, 9}, {7, 10}}}, {1/2 (1 - Sqrt[2]), {{1, 9}, {1, 
>       10}}}, {1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]), {{1, 7}, {1, 8}}}}

Comment: Thankxxx. It is very professional solution. Can you write the `SortBy[N @* First] @ lst` in a simpler way to understand how it does work.

Comment: I could not understand the mean of `@*`

Comment: @Inzo, it is short form for composition `Composition[N, First]`,  `N@*First` is the same function as `N[First@#]&`.

Answer (score 6):

```
list={{1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[2]), {{1, 11}, {1, 12}, {2, 11}}},{-1 - Sqrt[2], {{5, 11}, {5, 12}}},{1/2 (1 - Sqrt[2]), {{1, 9}, {1, 10}}}, {1 - Sqrt[2], {{7, 9}, {7, 10}}},{1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[2]), {{1, 7}, {1, 8}}}}   

SortBy[N@list,First]
```

> {{-2.41421, {{5., 11.}, {5., 12.}}}, {-1.20711, {{1., 11.}, {1., 
>       12.}, {2., 11.}}}, {-0.414214, {{7., 9.}, {7., 
>       10.}}}, {-0.207107, {{1., 9.}, {1., 10.}}}, {0.207107, {{1., 
>       7.}, {1., 8.}}}}